# How can I create a stacked bar chart from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using seaborn in Python (seaborn.histplot) with data stored in a dataframe, but when using & modifying code from class, I get the exception: **Invalid object at position 0. **

My x-value is type string (a variable created from cutting into quartiles), with my hue being a variable that is either 0 or 1.

Here is my current code for the stacked bar chart:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.histplot(data = df, x = "atndrte_q", hue="soph", multiple = "stack")
plt.title("Seaborn histplot with stack display\n" )
plt.show()
```

I am required to use seaborn for this problem.

It worked with the in class dataset to create a stacked bar chart, but it is not working with this one. It is just raising the exception of an invalid object at position 0.

If anyone has any ideas or can help explain what the excption means, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: It could be due to the datatype of the `atndrte_q` column. Try to convert the column to strings? `df['atndrte_q'] = df['atndrte_q'].astype(str)`?

Comment: @Redox Thank you! I totally overlooked that. I appreciate it!!